# One SSL cert two IIS6 web sites one domain

Tags: iis-6, domain, ssl-certificate

We have our main web site set up in IIS6 with an ssl cert for our domain "adomain.com".
We have another web site that we need to place on the same server which will be accessible via "adomain.com/newsite" each site has its own ip address.

We want to use the same ssl cert on both web site.

We dont want to have adomain.com/newsite under adomain.com website as they are seperate asp.net applications and adomain.com/newsite would inherit the adomain.com websies dlls and cause errors.

Is it possible to do what we are trying to do. I am a developer and not and sysAdmin so am a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates are issued for domains. They don't care what happens after the domain. If you set up your second site as described, you can use the same certificate, no problems. However, I don't think this will give you what you want. I am not a specialist on asp.net websites, but as far as I can tell "adomain.com/whatever" and "adomain.com/newsite" are effectively parts of the same website (namely "adomain.com"), and hence you WILL end up using the same dlls.

If that means that you really have to have a different domain, such as "new.adomain.com" vs. "www.adomain.com", then you either need a separate certificate for that, or you have to get yourself a certificate that covers more than one domain (which is possible, albeit at extra money).

Comment: Thanks, what steps would I take to setup the ssl cert for both sites in IIS. As each site will be in its own application pool with the routing done by the loadbalancer the two websites should be independant, I think. I will soon find out.

Comment: As said, I am not an export on IIS, I am sorry, I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

a loadbalancer can only route ssl encrypted traffic if it does the ssl itself, so either it won't work at all or you should be able to load the cert into the loadbalancer rather than into IIS